# Can I tap Sliver Hive to pay for Hive Stirrings?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I am playing a game and have no white mana to play [Hive Stirrings](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hive%20Stirrings), but I do have a [Sliver Hive](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sliver%20Hive) under my control. Am I able to tap the Sliver Hive to play Hive Stirrings (assume I have enough mana to play Hive Stirrings)?

Would this work?

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot use the coloured mana from [Sliver Hive](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sliver%20Hive) to cast [Hive Stirrings](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hive%20Stirrings).

[Sliver hive](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sliver%20hive) says

> Add one mana of any color to your mana pool. Spend this mana only to cast a Sliver spell.

But [Hive Stirrings](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hive%20Stirrings) is not a Sliver spell, it is only a Sorcery. This means you cannot use the coloured mana from Sliver hive to pay for the spell.

You can use the mana from Sliver Hive to play Creature - Sliver spells, or to play tribal sliver spells. There aren't any tribal sliver spells I can see, but you could play a changeling one such as [Wings of Velis Vel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wings%20of%20Velis%20Vel).